# php Mysqli - i want to change id number of some rows to end id

Tags: php, mysqli

my table has an id field with auto_increment and I want some rows to move to end of the table (changing number id to end number).

Like This:

```
$query= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE moshakhasat SET id=<?end table?> WHERE username='$username' ");
```

sorry about this code. I don't know a lot about PHP

I am tired and really need your help 
Thank you.

Comment: our help is with you only if you are explain a good question and post your efforts

Comment: how is that now?

Comment: id **is not a number**. you don't want to move it anywhere

Comment: Your query is heavily vulnerable to MySQL injection, you should look into [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) as this will protect you.

Comment: i want some rows go to end of table because when i send my rows in json it must be like this because i need to care rows Arrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sur if you can change that as mysql is handling the auto increment.
But maybe you could insert new row with your data and then delete the old row.

you could use the INSERT... SELECT syntax

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (field1, field2, ...)
  SELECT tbl1.field1, tbl1.field2
  FROM tbl1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

then

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: id **is not a number**. you **don't want** to move it anywhere

Comment: the question was asked on how to move some rows to the end of the table, the answer in question does just that, inserts new rows based on the old rows, and then removes the old rows, and autoincrement is a number, normaly integer, just be careful not to include the `id` column in the `select`